# Transform XML to display results. What to use XSLT or a POJO?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, pojo

The application I am working on receives a very complex XML as a response form an external system. The XML needs to be parsed to display results to the user.

I am trying to figure out the best approach to transform the XML to 'Display Ready' form. I have 2 options

1. Use XPATH to populate POJOs from XML which could be sent to the view layer for display.
2. Use XSLT transformation and display the results received in XML.

Which one would be faster? I understand that XSLT would get verbose and difficult to maintain.

Thanks in advance.

Shardul.

Comment: There shouldn't be significant difference in the speed of the two methods unless a poor algorithm is used in either of them. As for readability, flexibility and maintainability, XSLT is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for displaying only, I would prefer a XLST file.
But when you have to proces files in some sort way POJO will to the job